# SSRS --select All-- error

Tags: reporting-services

I have the below code in my query in SSRS 2008.

I added a parameter that will return a list of items based on a type group.

When I run the report based on individual type the results are successful however when I tried adding a `select all` attribute to the query, no results were returned.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemTable.ItemType
FROM            TABLE INNER JOIN
                         Table.Column ON Table.column= Table.column INNER JOIN
                         Table.column ON Table.column = Table.Column
UNION
SELECT        '--All--' AS Expr1
WHERE        ItemTable.ItemType= @TypeParameter) OR
                         (ItemTable.ItemType= '--All--')
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

It's difficult to tell without a Dataset to test against, but it should probably be something like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ItemTable.ItemType
FROM            TABLE INNER JOIN
                         Table.Column ON Table.column= Table.column INNER JOIN
                         Table.column ON Table.column = Table.Column
UNION
SELECT        '--All--' AS Expr1
FROM ItemTable
WHERE        ItemTable.ItemType= @TypeParameter OR 
                         @TypeParameter= '--All--'
```

I've changed the last line - previously if the parameter was `--All--` you were returning only rows where `ItemType` was `--All--` (i.e. probably none).

You need to run the last check against the parameter itself; if the parameter is `--All--`, that's when you want to return all rows.

**Edit after comments**

It's tough to try and debug your code without working example data.

Maybe something like:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT ItemTable.ItemType
FROM            TABLE INNER JOIN
                         Table.Column ON Table.column= Table.column INNER JOIN
                         Table.column ON Table.column = Table.Column
UNION
SELECT        '--All--' AS Expr1
) ItemTable
WHERE        ItemType= @TypeParameter OR
                         @TypeParameter= '--All--'
```

Comment: The @ type parameter returns three types DELETED , DISPOSED and SOLD OUT . that is the only types in that table , the --all-- I specified is an option I wan to be displayed together with the other 3 options on my dropdown list before I view report. I want to have a --all-- option so that when I select the --all-- it shouldn't just return the records of one type , but off all the times between the specified dates

Comment: I keep getting a error that says multi part identifier could not be bound to the ITEMTable.ItemType

Comment: I don't know how well your sample query represents your actual query. For example, in your example query you don't have a table in the second `SELECT` clause. I have added a table to my answer. If you want to supply a sample Dataset, please build one in http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: For you first question, the change I suggested should solve your problem - do you understand what I'm saying in the answer?

Comment: My sample query is identical to my actual query, and as for adding the table in the second select , I did that, but I am still getting the same error

Comment: OK, looking at the query again in the first `SELECT` you're selecting from `TABLE`, not `ItemTable`, so it's only natural you're getting the error. Your `INNER JOIN` clauses also don't have any tables specified. There are multiple syntax errors - I suggest you get your query running without the `WHERE` clause without the parameter check first.

Comment: without the where statement the query runs and the all is in the type list, however it returnsno results

Comment: Please provide your query and some sample data using a link to http://sqlfiddle.com/.

Comment: On My other dataset in the same report I have this select statement, I don't know if maybe that is also the cause?

Comment: SELECT        COUNT(*) AS RowsFound, Table.field
FROM            Table INNER JOIN
                         Table ON Table.field= Table.field INNER JOIN
                         table ON table.field= table.field WHERE        (table.modifiedon BETWEEN @StartDate AND @EndDate)
GROUP BY table.field
HAVING        (table.field= @TypeParameter)